# Does "Changed Owner (Assignment)" denote assignment rules?

Tags: assignment-rules, ownership, lead-owner

I'm trying to track down why a lead is randomly being reassigned and I want to confirm that when the lead history shows an ownership change with "Changed Owner (Assignment)" that indicates it was run through the lead assignment rules to cause the change? This would be in contrast to "Changed Lead Owner" which is done by a user (either manually or via an automated process).

Is that accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this annotation ("Assignment") means that the record was transferred specifically by an Assignment Rule, and not by any manual or otherwise automated process, including Workflow Rules, Apex Triggers, Flows, and Process Builder assignments. However, keep in mind that at least in Apex, you can use the [DmlOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm) class to recursive save the record and use Assignment Rules via the [AssignmentRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader.htm#apex_class_Database_AssignmentRuleHeader), including possibly a non-default Assignment Rule (by `assignmentRuleID`).